# What is the proper way to dispose of System.Timers.Timer?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a problem with the Timer class in that there is a chance that a timer would fire right before you call Dispose() since you will probably call Dispose() from some other thread. You may have something like:

```vb
Public Sub TimerTick() Handles itsTimer.Elapsed
   Do Something
End Sub
```

And then from somewhere else in the code, when your app is done, you call

```vb
itsTimer.Dispose()
```

The only way I can think of doing this is:

```vb
Public Sub SomeMethod()
   SyncLock(itsTimer.SynchronizingObject)
        itsTimer.Dispose()
   End SyncLock
ENd Sub
```

This is not a great thing to do esp. since I am holding a lock on an object I am disposing. I can create my own lock and syncLock on that but is there a simple way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locking the `SynchronizingObject` will not prevent the race condition. Neither will unregistering the tick event. In both cases, it's possible to have an event run after the timer is disposed.

You'd need to define a piece of shared state outside the timer that is explicitly checked at the beginning of your timer event handler. I call this an [asynchronous callback context](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/04/asynchronous-callback-contexts.html).

Answer (score 1):

[Unregister](http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/EventHandler.aspx) the tick event before disposing of the timer.

Use [`RemoveHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yyk8z93.aspx) to unregister the event handler.

Comment: How do you Unregister a "Handles" clause?

Comment: @Denis - You don't. Register the event with `AddHandler`.

Comment: Actually you can unregister with RemoveHandler even though the event has been set with Handles.

Comment: Just to add to what Meta-Knight said: The Handles keyword is just syntactic sugar for VB. When the VB compiler encounters it, it creates a property setter for the object(the Timer in this case) that automatically wires up the AddHandler/RemoveHandler calls.